Dayjs behave wired between mobile and web application
I am using this function to parse wall time of future event to user local timezone:
export const parseGatheringDate = (
  timeZone: string,
  gatheringData: {
    date: string;
    time: string;
    timeZone: string;
  }
) => {
  const eventDateTime = `${gatheringData.date}T${gatheringData.time}:00`;

  const gathering = dayjs.tz(eventDateTime, gatheringData.timeZone);

  const eventInLocalTime = gathering.tz(timeZone);

  const formattedEventTime = eventInLocalTime.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");

  return formattedEventTime;
};

And on web I am getting:
2024-08-21 02:00
2024-08-21 08:00

Which are correct values.
But on IOS simulator in react-native for the same code I am getting:
2024-08-21 06:44
2024-08-21 06:44

Test code is:
console.log(
      "DATE 1",
      parseGatheringDate("Europe/Belgrade", {
        date: "2024-08-21",
        time: "08:00",
        timeZone: "Europe/Belgrade",
      })
    );
    console.log(
      "DATE 2",
      parseGatheringDate("America/New_York", {
        date: "2024-08-21",
        time: "08:00",
        timeZone: "Europe/Belgrade",
      })
    );


Is this iOS specific? Does it work on Andoid?

Seems relevent: https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/issues/1377

... or one of these: https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+%22react+native%22+timezone

It seems it's not reliable to use so I switched to luxon in the end that one work perfect.
